# Using Custom Variables with PHP Prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Here I go... I have a search function for users, like this:

```
if ($_GET['s_country']){    
   $s_country = htmlentities($_GET['s_country'],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
   $s_country=trim($s_country);
   $s_country_row = " and country= ?";
} else {
   $s_country="";
   $s_country_row = " and (country= ? or not country= '')";
}
$s_city = "";
$s_city_row = " and (city= ? or not city= '')";
if ($_GET['s_city']){        
   $s_city = strip_tags($_GET['s_city']);
   $s_city=trim($s_city);
   $s_city_row = " and city= ?";
} 

$search = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE gender=? $s_country_row $s_city_row");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($search, 'iss', $s_gender, $s_country, $s_city);
```

In the above example I have used my own way to dismiss variables. I need to dismiss/remove variables that are not searched for or have no input.

If "country" is not searched for, it should return all rows with all "country" values.

**Is there any better way to do this?** (Without prepare statement it is quite easy to customize everything, but I hope security does not mean less flexibility).

Thank you for reading this

Answer (score 1):

```
$country = isset($_GET['s_country'])? " AND country=\'$_GET['s_country']\'" : '';
$query = " SELECT id FROM user WHERE gender=? $country ";
```

---

This is the pseudo idea
here query is forming in such a way that
- if it contains country then : SELECT id FROM user WHERE gender=? and country = 'US';
- if country is not defined then : SELECT id FROM user WHERE gender=?

as no conditions for country in the second query this will throw all country rows with particular gender

Comment: This would not work if I add any more rows and will throw an error, updated my question with more rows.

Comment: This is the flexibility that I want, but as a 100% prepared statement (this is what I meant  with my last sentence), in this example the variable $country is a huge security risk, I want this without MySQL injection probability.